# This payment method was declined IAP`s 4 Released and Beta App`s

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, payment

got a big issue @ Android.

All of my Apps are unable to proceed IAP`s, Sandbox Accounts and Real Customers.

Just get the info "This payment method was declined" for Paypal, Credit card and Balance.

No matter if Android 4.4.4 or 5.x.x is used.

I´m already using the V3 billing system.

The issue occures for some Apps since maybe 4 Weeks for another it just 2 Days old.

All Apps are made with Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today. Turns out I needed to fill the company form required by Google if your company is based in Europe.